# Error on Selecting nested List of Objects with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to write a typed dynamic projection method using dynamic linq in c#.

I only want to select certain fields of my Dtos even in nested Collections like Useraddresses from my example. The String selecting the required columns will be generated for this query:

```
query.Select<Domain.UserManagement>("new Domain.UserManagement.Users.User{ Id, firstname, lastname, email, 
UserAddresses.Select(new Domain.UserManagement.UserAddresses.UserAddress{ Country})
 as UserAddresses }").ToDynamicArray()
```

When i execute this i get

Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2147467261
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'expression')"
ParamName: "expression"
Source: "System.Linq.Expressions"
StackTrace: "   bei System.Dynamic.Utils.ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(Object value,
String paramName, Int32 index)\r\n   bei
System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName, Int32 idx)\r\n
bei System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member, Expression expression)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.CreateNewExpression(List`1 properties, List`1 expressions, Type newType)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseNew()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Par
ser.ExpressionParser.ParseShiftOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseComparisonOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAndOrOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIn()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAndOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseOrOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLambdaOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseNullCoalescingOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseConditionalOperator()\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType, Boolean createParameterCtor)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(Type delegateType, ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Ob
ject[] values)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.Select(IQueryable source, ParsingConfig config, String selector, Object[] args)\r\n   bei System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.Select(IQueryable source, String selector, Object[] args)"
TargetSite: {Void RequiresNotNull(System.Object, System.String, Int32)}

```
public abstract class Entity<TKey> : ICreatable, IDeletable, IEntityBase<TKey>
{
    [Key]
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity<Guid>
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}

    public class UserAddress : Entity<Guid>
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNr { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was
ICollection UserAddresses instead of IEnumerable in User Class